# Python: copying dictionary inside function modifies also original copy

Tags: python, dictionary, copy, deep-copy

I have a small script calculating the tax for a basket of items. It works by creating a new key "tax" with the correct value. As I don't want to change the original dictionary I shallow copy the input dictionary.
To my surprise this code also changes the original dictionary data. Can you explain me why?

```
data = {'book': {'n': 2, 'price': 12.49},
 'music CD': {'n': 1, 'price': 14.99},
 'chocolate bar': {'n': 1, 'price': 0.85}}

exceptions = ["book","food","chocolate", "headache pills"]

def computeTaxes(order):

ord = order.copy()

for item,value in ord.items():

    #calculate basic tax
    if any(ex in item for ex in exceptions):
        ord[item]['tax'] = 0

    else:
        ord[item]['tax'] = 0.10 * ord[item]['price']

    #calculate import duty
    if "import" in item:
        ord[item]['tax'] += 0.05 * ord[item]['price']

return ord

computeTaxes(data)

# data is now: 
{'book': {'n': 2, 'price': 12.49, 'tax': 0},
 'music CD': {'n': 1, 'price': 14.99, 'tax': 1.499},
 'chocolate bar': {'n': 1, 'price': 0.85, 'tax': 0}}
```

Comment: A shallow copy will not copy the nested dictionaries. You want a deep copy.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the copy library

```
import copy
```

replace `ord = order.copy()` by `ord = copy.deepcopy(order)`

Comment: @Kevin: `order.copy()` does in fact create a new object. It does not create new copies of objects the original dict holds references to, though.